# Littlewood polynomial and Gutzmer-Parseval inequality

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the set of Littlewood polynomial for $n \geq 1$, ie

$$ L_n = \left \{ a_0 + a_1 z + \cdots + a_n z^n: \quad a_j = \pm 1 \right \} $$

By Gutzmer-Parseval inequality, for some $f \in L_n$, we have

$$ \sqrt{n+1} \leq M(f,1) \leq n+1, \quad M(f,1) = \max_{|z|=1} |f(z)| $$

Question: Is it possible to find a sequence $f_n \in L_n$ with

$$ M(f_n, 1) \leq C \sqrt{n+1}, \forall n \geq 1 $$

In this case the constant $C>0$ depends of the sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The Rudin-Shapiro polynomials work. Define inductively the pair $(P_n, Q_n)$ by $P_0 = Q_0 = 1$ and
$$ \begin{aligned}
P_n(z) &= P_{n-1}(z) + z^{2^{n-1}} Q_{n-1}(z) \\
Q_n(z) &= P_{n-1}(z) - z^{2^{n-1}} Q_{n-1}(z).
\end{aligned} $$
One can verify that these are Littlewood polynomials with Fourier support  $[0,2^n - 1].$ We have
$$
\lvert P_n(z) \rvert^2 + \lvert Q_n(z) \rvert^2 = 2^{n+1}
$$
on the circle so that $\| P_n \|_\infty$ is about $2^{n/2}$, as desired. It should be possible to find Littlewood polynomials with Fourier support $[0,n-1]$ with the desired property by patching together these polynomials, losing just a factor of (I think) $2$ in $\| \cdot \|_\infty$ in the process.

It is an open problem to find a sequence of Littlewood polynomials $(f_n)$ with $\lvert f_n(z) \rvert \geq C \sqrt{n + 1}$ on the circle.